# Help me get Engraved source blocks working

Tags: org-mode

In Org mode mode am trying to export source blocks to Latex using [`engrave-faces`](https://github.com/tecosaur/engrave-faces). My `init.el` includes the following.

```
(use-package engrave-faces
  :ensure t
  :init
  (setq org-latex-src-block-backend 'engraved))
```

But the exported source blocks are formatted according to Org mode's defaults and aren't *engraved*. Does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: The doc string of `org-latex-src-block-backend` says: `... This requires the Emacs package engrave-faces (available from ELPA), and the LaTeX package fvextra be installed.` Maybe you are missing the latter?

Comment: Sadly not. I have `fvextra` installed. Engraving was working for me at some point, but has stopped. I think this was after a system update, though what exactly broke it I don't know. Thank you for the suggestion.